# PHP dynamic form will not INSERT into mySql

Tags: php, forms, dynamic

I'm working on a PHP dynamic form based on the tutorial found here:
http://blog.calendarscripts.info/dynamically-adding-input-form-fields-with-jquery/

Here is the table layout:

ID | depratecat | MinBalance | InterestRate | APY | suborder
inputted rows

ID is auto-increment. 
The form fields for depratecat are visible in my code only for testing; normally the user would not be able to change this value. The value of depratecat would come from a POST value from a previous page and should be the same for all rows inputted or edited in this instance. For testing I'm declaring the value as 14.

My test page is here:
http://www.bentleg.com/fcsbadmin/dynamictest4.php

The problems:
The "Add row" script function does not work and the code won't insert new data thru form; nothing happens. No errors are shown in the Chrome console

Editing or deleting pre-existing rows seems to work.

Below is my complete test code minus the connection, Some print_r added to show the array.:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
// Connect to the DB
$link = myconnection stuff

$new_depratecat='14'; //for testing


// store in the DB 
if(!empty($_POST['ok'])) { 
//first delete the records marked for deletion. Why? Because we don't want to process them in the code below
if( !empty($_POST['delete_ids']) and is_array($_POST['delete_ids'])) {
// you can optimize below into a single query, but let's keep it simple and clear for now:
foreach($_POST['delete_ids'] as $id) {
$sql = "DELETE FROM tblRates_balance WHERE id=$id";
$link->query($sql);
}
}

// now, to edit the existing data, we have to select all the records in a variable.
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblRates_balance WHERE depratecat='$new_depratecat' ORDER BY suborder";
$result = $link->query($sql);

// now edit them
while($rates = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

// remember how we constructed the field names above? This was with the idea to access the values easy now
$sql = "UPDATE tblRates_balance SET 
MinBalance='".$_POST['MinBalance'.$rates['id']]."', 
InterestRate='".$_POST['InterestRate'.$rates['id']]."',
APY='".$_POST['APY'.$rates['id']]."',
suborder='".$_POST['suborder'.$rates['id']]."'
WHERE id='$rates[id]'";


$link->query($sql);


}
// (feel free to optimize this so query is executed only when a rate is actually changed)

// adding new

if($_POST['add_MinBalance']!= "") { 

//echo ("OKAY");

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblRates_balance (depratecat, MinBalance, InterestRate, APY, suborder) VALUES ('$new_depratecat','".$_POST['add_MinBalance']."', '".$_POST['add_InterestRate']."', '".$_POST['add_APY']."','".$_POST['add_suborder']."' );";

$link->query($sql);

}
}

// select existing rates here
$sql="SELECT * FROM tblRates_balance where depratecat='$new_depratecat' ORDER BY suborder";
$result = $link->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Example of dynamically adding row and inserting into mySql with jQuery</title>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div style="width:90%;margin:auto;">
<h1>Example of dynamically adding row and inserting into mySql with jQuery </h1>

<form method="POST" id="newrate">
<div id="itemRows">

Minimum Balance: <input type="text" name="add_MinBalance" size="30" /> 
Interest Rate: <input type="text" name="add_InterestRate" /> 
APY: <input type="text" name="add_APY" /> 
Order: <input type="text" name="add_suborder" size="2"/> 


<< Add data and click on "Save Changes" to insert into db. <br>
You can add a new row and make changes to existing rows all at one time and click on "Save Changes."
New entry row will appear above after saving.

<?php
// Next section does updating. let's assume you have the rate data from the DB in variable called $rates

while($rates = mysqli_fetch_array($result)): ?>
<p id="oldRow<?=$rates['id']?>">
<?php //echo $rates['id']; ?>

Minimum Balance: <input type="text" name="MinBalance<?=$rates['id']?>" value="<?=$rates['MinBalance']?>" />
Interest Rate: <input type="text" name="InterestRate<?=$rates['id']?>" value="<?=$rates['InterestRate']?>" /> 

APY: <input type="text" name="APY<?=$rates['id']?>" value="<?=$rates['APY']?>" />
Order: <input type="text" name="suborder<?=$rates['id']?>" value="<?=$rates['suborder']?>" />
<input type="checkbox" name="delete_ids[]" value="<?=$rates['id']?>"> Mark to delete</p>
<?php endwhile;?>

</div>

<p><input type="submit" name="ok" value="Save Changes"></p>
</form>

</div>

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">


var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
rowNum ++; 
var row = '<p id="rowNum'+rowNum+'">Minimum Balance:<input type="text" name="add_MinBalance[]" value="'+frm['add_MinBalance[]'].value+'">Interest Rate:<input type="text" name="add_InterestRate[]" value="'+ frm['add_InterestRate[]'].value +'">APY:<input type="text" name="add_APY[]" value="'+frm['add_APY[]'].value+'">Order:<input type="text" name="add_suborder[]"value="'+ frm['add_suborder[]'].value+'"><input type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+rowNum+')(this);"></p>';
jQuery('#itemRows').append(row);
frm['add_MinBalance[]'].value = '';
frm['add_InterestRate[]'].value = '';
frm['add_APY[]'].value = '';
frm['add_suborder[]'].value = '';

}

function removeRow(rnum) {
jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
}

//}
</script>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please, learn to use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 1):

The inputs in the initial form have names `add_depratecat`, `add_MinBalance`, `add_InterestRate`, `add_APY`, and `add_suborder`. When you add new rows, they have the same names, but with `[]` appended. So the original row creates single inputs, the added rows create array inputs, but they have the same names, and they conflict.

You should use the array form for the original inputs as well:

```
<form method="POST" id="newrate">
    <div id="itemRows">
    Dep_rate_cat:<input type="text" name="add_depratecat[]" size="30"/> 
    Minimum Balance: <input type="text" name="add_MinBalance[]" size="30" /> 
    Interest Rate: <input type="text" name="add_InterestRate[]" /> 
    APY: <input type="text" name="add_APY[]" /> 
     Order: <input type="text" name="add_suborder[]" size="2"/>
```

so that they're consistent with the added rows.

Comment: Now a new problem. When I append the [] as you suggested, the "Add row" function fails. That is, a new row is not added when clicking "Add row".

Comment: Errors in console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined dynamictest4.php:55
addRow dynamictest4.php:55
onclick dynamictest4.php:26

Comment: Since you changed the names of the fields, you have to update things like `frm.add_depratecat.value` to match. That should be `frm['add_depratacat[]'].value`. Or you can assign IDs to the elements and use `document.getElementById('add_depratacat').value`.

Comment: I made the changes but the same error is occuring in the Chrome console and the new row is still not being added. Here is the script after I made the updates. Did I do it wrong?  code

Comment: I mean I made the changes to my original code block. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I don't know anything about fiddle. I've added some more echos and echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); to my code above to try to see whats going on.

Comment: You have a typo: `frm['add__APY[]'].value` should be `frm['add_APY[]'].value` -- you have an extra underscore.

Comment: I've fixed that typo and edited my code above. However, still the code will still not perform the INSERT: http://www.bentleg.com/fcsbadmin/dynamictest4.php

Comment: `$depratacat = $_POST['add_depratecat[]'];` should be `$depratacat $_POST['add_depratecat'];`.

Comment: Also fix the `isset` line before that.

Comment: Another error: `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);'</pre>';` You need `echo` before `'</pre>'`.

Comment: Thanks to you, I now have the form and INSERTS working. I've made edits above. However, now if I use the Addrow function to add a new rate and then click "SaveChanges" the new row is entered twice. Also if I try to delete a row using "Mark to Delete" the row is deleted but a new row is added with values = 0. Can you take a look and see whats causing this? You can see the issue online here:  http://www.bentleg.com/fcsbadmin/dynamictest15.php

Comment: Please don't remove the original, bad code in your question. If you want to show your changes, add an UPDATE at the end of the question. Otherwise, how will readers see the original errors that my answer was fixing?

Comment: One problem: `value="<?=$rates['depratecat']?> ?>"` you have an extra `?>` at the end. But I don't think that's causing the duplicate row or deletion problem.

Comment: The row with zero values is coming from the blank `add_depratecat[]` row that you have at the beginning of the form. You should only add a row to the database if the user has actually filled in the fields.

Comment: Thank you. I made the correction. I just noticed that the extra row insertion is also happening if I update a existing row. The update is performed but another "0" row is inserted.

Comment: That's correct. Your form always starts with a blank row at the top, and that row is used to insert a row into the table. Maybe you should leave that row out, and make the user click on "Add row" when they want to add a row.

Comment: I have edited my code above. Still one problem I can't figure out, the user should not enter the Rate Category, that's supposed to come from $new_depratecat ='14'; at the start of the page. When I change form code to this:  Rate category: <input type="text" name="add_depratecat[]" size="30" value="<?php echo $new_depratecat; ?>"/> the problem of extra rows added still occurs if updating or deleting a row. How can I have the depratecat auto generated with the double delete or update issue?

Comment: Did you really just edit the code in the question again, even though I specifically said NOT TO DO THAT? How is anyone supposed to understand this answer if you keep changing the question?

Comment: I apologize, I though I was doing what you instricted me to do.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm done here. I can only spend so much time on one question. I can't teach you how to program, you either know what you're doing or you don't.

Comment: I'm a newbie, I've been spending hours studying, but still needed some help. I very much appreciate the time and effort you have put into this. Thank you.

Comment: I have resolved the issues and edited my original code to show the successful page for any others needing help with this problem.

Comment: You still don't get how SO works. The question is supposed to contain the BROKEN code, not the working code.

Comment: The fix should go in an answer. If you want to answer your own question, that is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Initially you are not adding `[]` in the form fields,

change `<input type="text" name="add_depratecat" size="30">` to `<input type="text" name="add_depratecat[]" size="30">`, do the same for other fields as well.

And in `foreach` where you are inserting data to database use array `$depratecat[]` instead of string `$depratecat`

```
if(isset($_POST['add_depratecat'])) {   
        $depratecat = $_POST['add_depratecat']; ........
```

For debugging purpose write `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);` OR `var_dump($_POST);` Instead of 
`echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST,true),'</pre>';`.